# Не переходит по ссылкам тест

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Есть файл с набором методов для selenium WebDriver на java. И есть тест. Тест открывает браузер, заходит на страницу, но потом падает, по ссылкам не переходит. И ничего поделать с этим не могу. 
Может я неправильно метод добавил или еще что... Дайте совет: Два метода надо добавить: getClickableElement и getVisibleElement. Сейчас методы есть, но если через них пишу, падает с ошибкой "Элемент не кликабелен", но я уверен что это не так. Или еще как Кликать и вводить текст, подскажите.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import com.selenium.test.configuration.TestsConfig;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class WebDriverFactory {
    private static final long IMPLICIT_WAIT_TIMEOUT = 25;
    private static WebDriver driver;
    private static WebDriverWait sWebDriverWait;


    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        if (driver != null) {
            return driver;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Driver has not been initialized. " + "Please call WebDriverFactory.startBrowser() before use this method");
        }
    }


    public static void startBrowser(boolean isLocal) {
        if (driver == null) {
            Browser browser = TestsConfig.getConfig().getBrowser();
            if (!isLocal) {
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(CapabilitiesGenerator.getDefaultCapabilities(browser));
            } else {
                switch (browser) {
                    case FIREFOX:
                        driver = new FirefoxDriver(CapabilitiesGenerator.getDefaultCapabilities(Browser.FIREFOX));
                        break;
                    // case FIREFOX:
                    // break;
                    case CHROME:
                        driver = new ChromeDriver(CapabilitiesGenerator.getDefaultCapabilities(Browser.CHROME));
                        break;
                    case IE10:
                        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(CapabilitiesGenerator.getDefaultCapabilities(Browser.IE10));
                        break;
                    case SAFARI:
                        driver = new SafariDriver(CapabilitiesGenerator.getDefaultCapabilities(Browser.SAFARI));
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported browser type");
                }
            }
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(IMPLICIT_WAIT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Driver has already been initialized. Quit it before using this method");
        }
    }



    public static void finishBrowser() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
            driver = null;
        }
    }



   public static WebElement getClickableElement(By by) {
        try {
            sWebDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
            WebElement element = null;
            element = element.findElement(by);
            return element;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Элемент" + by.toString() + "не является кликабельным. \n");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static WebElement getVisibleElement(By by) {
        try {
            return sWebDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Элемент" + by.toString() + "не является видимым на странице. \n");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println();
            return null;
        }
    }



    public static void takeScreenShot() {
        System.out.println("ScreenShot method called");
    }

}
```

Вот сам тест.

```
  import com.selenium.test.junit.rules.ScreenShotOnFailRule;
import com.selenium.test.webtestsbase.WebDriverFactory;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;


public class SimpleTest {

    @Before
    public void beforeTest() {
        WebDriverFactory.startBrowser(true);
    }


    @Test
    public void testMainCredit() {
        String toSearch = "Selenium";
        WebDriverFactory.getDriver().get("http://www.mtsbank.ru");
        WebDriverFactory.getVisibleElement(By.cssSelector("#oldFormMTSBank__phone")).click();

    }


    @After
    public void afterTest() {
        WebDriverFactory.finishBrowser();
    }

}
```

Comment: Я дам пару советов по оформлению вопросов.1) Не тратьте свое и чужое время на приветствия -- это не форум, а сайт вопросов и ответов; 2) Формулируйте вопрос именно в виде вопроса: "Как сделать...?" "Почему не работает...?" и т. п. 3) Старайтесь соблюдать правила грамматики и пунктуации -- это облегчает понимание. Люди, которые могут дать полезный ответ -- как правило, люди занятые и время им дорого.

Comment: а где ссылка на сайт, путь к элемену, которую хотите кликнуть? код, который это делает? Приложите к вопросу, пожалуйста

Comment: И не загроможайте пример кода деталями, не относящисимися к теме вопроса. Уберите из кода всё лишнее, прежде чем помещать его сюда.

Comment: @СергейБогданов, а где код самого теста?.. `getClickableElement()` , `getVisibleElement()` , `takeScreenShot()` , `finishBrowser()` , `startBrowser()` , `getDriver()` - это все вспомогательные методы....где `run()` или ему подобный метод?.

Comment: @СергейБогданов, оставьте методы, `getClickableElement()` , `getVisibleElement()`  - остальное удалите. и добавьте код самого теста и желательно ссылку по которой можно будет понять к чему вы хотите обратиться.

Comment: @МихаилРебров Cсылка в тесте, а весь первый код, чтобы вся картина виделась.

Answer (score 0):

праблема в том, что сайт еще не открылся, а мы уже пытаемся искать элемент. Много кто для таких целей ждут с помощью  Awaitility

Например,

```
 Waiter.await()
            .atMost(TIMEOUT_SEC, SECONDS)
            .pollInterval(1, SECONDS)
            .ignoreExceptionsInstanceOf(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
            .until(element.isDisplayed());
```

вам нужно подождать немного после загрузки сайта

```
    driver.get("http://www.mtsbank.ru");

    Thread.sleep(500L);
    WebElement element = getVisibleElement(By.cssSelector("#oldFormMTSBank__phone"));
    element.click();

    driver.quit();
```

Comment: Я сразу тоже так подумал. Но нет. Поменял методы и все заработало. Применил findElement